# How to declare Typings for a context hook whose value is return of a useReducer hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having trouble defining the types for a context hook return type whose value is the return type of a useReducer hook.

```
export const StateContext = createContext([{}]); // How to define the defaultValue here

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }: {reducer: any, initialState: IStore, children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider
    value={useReducer<React.Reducer<IStore, IAction>>(reducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

This will be used as this:

```
const [store, dispatch] = useStateValue();
```

I am unable to define the type for createContext

Comment: put a default value into the useState, and it will assume that type. It could be a union to cater for variability.